# Логирование ошибок БД

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую!
Например

```
mysql_connect('','','') or die ('Error database');
```

При ошибке выведет ошибка бд, а как вывести эту фразу, но и саму ошибку тоже словить и записать в файл лога, и смотреть? думаю как-то через исключения... Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_connect('','','') or your_function(mysql_error());

function your_function($err){
//
//тут код записывающий в фаил
//
echo $err; //вывод
}
```

п.с Конкретно ф-я  mysql_error()  выдаст конкретно ошибку которую вернет мускуль. Если хотите озвучивать ошибки своими текстами, то вместо нее как у вас сделайте 'текст ошибки'
А лучше передавайте 2 параметра. 1 ошибка мускуля, вторая для вывода пользователю. Чтоб он видел просто что не подключился мускуль, а вы почему.Упал,не верный пароль,нет базы и т.д

Тогда ф-я станет универсальной и даже для селектов,инсертов,делетов  ее можно использовать и в лог получать отрывок запроса проблемного.

А вообще советую вот тут вот : http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php
Прочитать комментарии. Там сотни примеров как записывать ошибку вместе с проблемным запросом, использовать mysql_errno() получать код ошибки и т.д Куча готовых вариантов)